# API response is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I am making a API call that returns a JSON response of an Array with a bunch of objects. Each object has a key "dt" that is the timestamp of a specific time of day and another key of "height" which is the Ocean's predicted or past tide height at that moment in time.

I only want the current tide's height at whatever moment in time the AJAX call happens. This is the function I created in order to achieve that:

```
let tideApi = 'https://www.worldtides.info/api?heights&lat=45.202&lon=-123.963&key=24e4ff14-6edf-4f79-9591-e47f9e0e21e1';

$.getJSON(tideApi, function(response) {

  // Create Global variable
  let tideHeight = 0;
  // get current time
  let nowMil = new Date().getTime();
  // round that time to the nearest halfhour and convert back to timestamp (JSON timestamps are set in intervals of 30 minutes)
  let timeNow = Math.round(nowMil/1000/60/30) * 30 * 60 * 1000;

  // set entire array to variable
  let heightArray = response.heights;
  // get length
  len = heightArray.length
  // loop through each object in height array
  for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
    // if one of the objects timestamp equals current time
    if (i.dt = timeNow) {
      // set tide height to variable
      tideHeight = i.height;
      // return tide height (curretly returning undefined)
      console.log("Tide Height: " + tideHeight);
      return tideHeight;
    } else {
      console.log("Error, no time found");
    }
  }
  // put tide height into div
  $("#tideStat").append("<p>" + tideHeight + "</p>");

});
```

It's currently returning undefined for a reason I am struggling to figure out. Any help would be great!

[API Call](https://www.worldtides.info/api?heights&lat=45.202&lon=-123.963&key=24e4ff14-6edf-4f79-9591-e47f9e0e21e1) (Don't worry going to change after this)

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/thatemployee/pen/RLPmoe?editors=1010)

Comment: `if (i.dt = timeNow)` and other properties of an integer ???

Comment: I'm sorry I am unclear of what you are asking. Could you please be more specific? @Teemu

Comment: How specific I should be? I pointed out, that you're trying to read some properties of an integer, which obviously are not defined ... As a bonus, you can see, that you're using the assignment operator instead of an equality operator in the condition.

Comment: Specific enough that I don't have to ask you to be more clear on what '???' means. I am just trying to understand better on how to improve my logic is all. We are all just trying to learn my friend. I'm not sure why the integer is not defined. Is there a clear reason for this? @Teemu

Comment: It is defined, but it is a number you declared at the line above, and set`0`  to it. A number obviously don't have any properties defined in the AJAX response.

Comment: It's difficult to understand you when you give a vague response, then I answer asking you to write full sentences and you edit your old answers to seem more precise. Thank you for trying to contribute but I will not be giving attention to these comments anymore. @Teemu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code

1. `let timeNow = Math.round(nowMil/1000/60/30) * 30 * 60 * 1000;`. Your API doesn't seem to be returning milliseconds. Remove the `* 1000`.
2. You're not accessing items from your `heightArray`. Rather, just checking `dt` and `height` property on `i`, which is an integer. So change `i.dt` and `i.height` to `heightArray[i].dt` and `heightArray[i].height` respectively.
3. When you use `if (lhs = rhs)`, you're attempting to *assign*, not *compare*. So, change `=` to `===` in the `if` condition.
4. Remove `return tideHeight;`. I think you want [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break)? Not sure though. Because of this line, your last `jQuery` related code doesn't execute.

[Forked pen](https://codepen.io/sniper6/pen/gGPwZX?editors=1011). Some logs commented out for better output.

Comment: You are awesome, thank you very much. In addition thank you for educating me why my code was wrong and the mistakes I made so I didn't do them again. There is no such thing as a stupid question, even if it has an obvious answer. Everyone has to to start from somewhere. I'm not a big fan on any environment where people are discouraged from asking questions and it seems SO as provided that recently. Faith restored in the community.

Answer (score 1):

Use bracket notation to reference `i` object of `heightArray` array, `===` operator, instead of `=`, which is assignment operator

```
if (heightArray[i].dt === timeNow) {
  // do stuff
  tideHeight = heightArray[i].height;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is definitely a huge help. I am now hitting the error catch statement so I will do some troubleshooting on that. You did answer my question on why it was returning undefined so I will accept you as an answer.

Comment: What is expected result of `return tideHeight`?

Comment: A height property from an object with the same dt timestamp as the present time.

Comment: Do you chain `.then()` to `$.getJSON()` to get `return`ed value?

Comment: @thatemployee Ah, you are expecting the `for` loop to `break` and have access to `tideHeight` at `$("#tideStat").append("<p>" + tideHeight + "</p>");`